# Weak derivative of maximum

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

At some point in a lesson in Calculus of Variations, my teacher had a function defined as:

$$v(x)=
\begin{cases}
u(x) & x\notin B(x_0,3\delta) \\
\max\{R(2\eta-1),u\} & x\in B(x_0,3\delta)
\end{cases},$$

where $u$ was the $W^{1,p}$ solution to some variational problem (with fast growth of the lagrangian IIRC), $x_0$ was a point in the (bounded IIRC) domain $\Omega$ of integration, $\delta$ was picked so that the ball in the definition of $v$ was contained in $\Omega$, $R$ was basically the sup of $u$ in the ball, and $\eta$ was a smooth transition from 1 in $B(x_0,\delta)$, to 0 outside $B(x_0,2\delta)$ (maybe we only needed $\mathcal{C}^1$, but I don't think this is relevant to the question). He justified it being weakly differentiable by saying roughly that, where it is defined as a max, it is $[R(2\eta-1)-u]^+$, where $[\cdot]^+$ is the positive part. Now I saw immediately that this was not true: e.g., if we consider $\max\{x,-x\}$, we get $|x|$, whereas $[x-(-x)]^+=[2x]^+=2x^+$. So I tried working on a proof myself. I noticed that we can write:

$$\max\{f,g\}=[f-g]^++[g-f]^++g\cdot I_{\{f\geq g\}}+f\cdot I_{\{f<g\}},$$

so I concentrated on $g\cdot I_{\{f\geq g\}}$, trying to prove it belonged to $W^{1,p}$. I tried a smoothing approach. I noticed the indicator could be written as $\theta\circ(f-g)$, where $\theta=I_{[0,+\infty)}$ (closed half-line), so I first smoothed out $\theta$ with:

$$\theta_\epsilon(x)=
\begin{cases}
\theta(x) & x\notin[-\epsilon,0] \\
p_\epsilon(x) & x\in[-\epsilon,0]
\end{cases},$$

where I determined that the choice:

$$p_\epsilon(x)=-\frac{3}{\epsilon^3}x^3-\frac{2}{\epsilon^2}x^2+1$$

makes $\theta_\epsilon$ a $\mathcal{C}^1$ function. It is easy to show (dominated convergence) that $\theta_\epsilon\circ v\to\theta\circ v$ in $L^p$. Trouble is, what happens when I add $g$ back in? I didn't notice the problem until a long session of gradient work, in which I found $v_n$ converging in $W^{1,p}$ to $v$ and being smooth on $\Omega$, assumed they converged pointwise a.e. (modulo choosing a subsequence), showed $\theta_\epsilon\circ v_{n_k}\to\theta_\epsilon\circ v$ in $L^p$ via dominated  convergence, computed the gradients with the rule that $(q\circ s)'=q'\circ s\cdot s'$ when $q\in W^{1,p}$ and $s$ is $\mathcal{C}^1$, proved those gradients converged to the analog with $v$, concluded by the closing lemma that $(\theta_\epsilon\circ v)'=\theta_\epsilon'\circ v\cdot v'$ (well, this works for any partial $\partial_k$, but I was to lazy to write $\partial_k$ out :) ), hence $\theta_\epsilon\circ v$ is $W^{1,p}$, and then I said and what about $g\theta_\epsilon\circ v$? So is it true that the weak derivative of $\max\{f,g\}$, that is of $f\cdot I_{\{f\geq g\}}+g\cdot I_{\{f<g\}}$, is the most natural guess one would try, i.e. $\nabla f\cdot I_{\{f\geq g\}}+\nabla g\cdot I_{\{f<g\}}$? And how do I prove it?

**Note**

Naturally, once we have that formula for the weak gradient, the max is automatically Sobolev, since $f,g$ are, and $\int|\nabla(\max)|^p$ can be estimated via convexity in terms of $\int|\nabla f|^p$ and $\int|\nabla g|^p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f, g$ are in $W^{1,p}$, it is in general not true that $g I_{f\ge g}$ is in $W^{1,p}$. Think it this way: If $p >n$, then the Sobolev imbedding theorem implies that all functions in $W^{1,p}$ are continuous. But one can find $f, g$ so that $g I_{f\ge g}$ is not continuous thus not in $W^{1,p}$ (for example, $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = 1$ in $\Omega = (0,2)$).

Instead, using

$$\max \{ f, g\} = \frac  12(f+g+ |f-g|),$$

it suffices to show that $|f-g|$ is weakly differentiable. But this follows from Lemma 7.5 and Lemma 7.6 in Gilbarg and Trudinger (If you do not have access to the book, I can provide a proof here)

Comment: Knowing $f-g$ is in $W^{1,p}$, all that is left is to prove $W^{1,p}$ is closed under absolute value. And I have a proof of that, which first establishes closure of $W^{1,p}$ under posiive and negative part (positive part bu approximating $\max\{t,0\}$ with $\mathcal C^1$ functions $\sqrt{\max\{t,0\}+\epsilon^2}$ and showing these composed with a $W^{1,p}$ function converge in $L^p$ to that function and then showing what the gradients converge to, negative part by saying "similarly"), and then says "we have p.p. and n.p., sum them and voilà the absolute value".

Comment: Btw since $\min\{f,g\}=\frac12(|f-g|-f-g)$, we obtain a similar result for minima of Sobolev functions.

Comment: Btw I do have access. [Lemma 7.5](http://i.stack.imgur.com/R3lny.png) is a form of chain rule (if $f$ is $\mathcal{C}^1$ and bounded and $u$ is weakly differentiable then $f\circ u$ has weak derivative $f'\circ u\cdot u'$, where $'$ can be substituted by any $\partial_k$ on $u$ but $f$ has to be real-valued and of real variable), and I have seen this proved in another course, IIRC one approximates $u$ with smooth functions (perhaps convolutions?) and shows the derivatives of $f\circ u_n$ converge to that and concludes by closing lemma, and [Lemma 7.6](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cHceA.png)…

Comment: …is positive part, negative part and absolute value, as discussed in the first comment. I guess the proof is that one.